# protobuf-net.Grpc serializing Interfaces

Tags: protobuf-net, protobuf-net.grpc

I am facing some difficulty serializing an interface using CodeFirst in Protobuf-net.grpc. It is a DataMember within a DataContract. It works fine when I use it in a simple console application but when I try to use it in a different project with the same references, it doesn't serialize. I can see this error in the Visual studio output as well, when the AddCodeFirst is done on the gRPC Server :

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
> protobuf-net.dll

This is the code I have for the DataContract in both my project and the dummy application

```
using ProtoBuf;

namespace ProtoBufTesting.Prepare
{
    [DataContract, ProtoContract]
    public class ExtensionData
    {
        public ExtensionData() { }

        public ExtensionData(
            string extensionName,
            string packageIdentifier,
IExtensionCertificateCollection collection)
        {
            this.ServiceName = extensionName;
            this.PackageIdentifier = packageIdentifier;
            this.CertificateCollection = collection;
        }

        [DataMember]
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string ServiceName
        {
            get; private set;
        }

        [DataMember]
        [ProtoMember(4)]

        public string PackageIdentifier
        {
            get; private set;
        }

        [DataMember]
        [ProtoMember(5)]

        public IExtensionCertificateCollection CertificateCollection { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

This is the interface IExtensionCertificateCollection that has the ProtoContract decorator which works in my sample project.

```
namespace ProtoBufTesting
{
    [ProtoContract]
    public interface IExtensionCertificateCollection
    {

        IExtensionCertificate GetByThumbprint(string thumbprint);

        IEnumerable<IExtensionCertificate> AllCertificates { get; }
    }
}
```

This is the service contract that uses the ExtensionData DataContract

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "blah")]
public interface IRTC
{

    [OperationContract]
    ExtensionData PrepareExtension(PrepareExtensionInput input);

}
```

This is how I do the Code First setup if you see below.
This works perfectly fine other than in the second project where I'm doing the same thing. I am really not sure how to go about debugging this. The reason I did a sample console application is to test if Interfaces serialize using ProtoContract decorators and they did successfully with just the ProtoContract decorator... But when I started using it in a larger project (same interface definition and data contract), it just doesn't seem to serialize the DataContract. It only serializes the DataContract when I remove that interface from the the Datamember. Any ideas how I should go about debugging this to find out what is causing this? I've been stuck on this for a few hours. Other than the InvalidOperationException, I don't see any other errors in the VS output.

```
Server server = new Server
            {
                Ports = { new ServerPort("localhost", ServerPort.PickUnused , ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
            };

            server.Services.AddCodeFirst(new RTC());
            server.Start();
            int port = server.Ports.Single().BoundPort;

            Console.WriteLine("server listening on port " + port);

            GrpcClientFactory.AllowUnencryptedHttp2 = true;

            Channel channel = new Channel("localhost", port, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
            

            var rtc = channel.CreateGrpcService<IRTC>();
```

***Update:***

I figured out a different way to 'debug' this - using this method below. It parsed the schema of the object I'm trying to serialize. Putting a try catch with this specific object gave me an error atleast! "Tags must be positive integers". I found this issue and fixed it.

```
ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default.GetSchema(typeof(ExtensionData));
```

But after that error, I still keep getting the previous still and that doesn't seem to resolve. I'm running this under a Unit test method and it only shows a high level error like this during the AddCodeFirst - I added a TraceWriter in the AddCodeFirst and this is what it says -

```
[warning] Type cannot be serialized; ignoring: ExtensionData
[warning] Signature not recognized for PrepareExtension; method will not be bound
```

How do I go about investigating this further? This is linked to the previous error I still get:

Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in protobuf-net.dll

Comment: Further update, tried the same in a separate new console application using the same classes and still see that they are not getting bound to the service with the same error and no more details even on the Console. Earlier thought the unit test is blocking specific grpc errors but same in console now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this. Lots of types associated to the interface (and others) that were not getting deserialized correctly. I didn't see this in any error log though which made it hard to find.. searching online /looking through codebehind for protobuf-grpc.. it looked like adding explicit registrations of all the types that are required to be deserialized by the interface is required, else it won't work.

I don't know if there is a better way to do this, but this was required just prior to the grPC AddCodeFirst else the service didn't ever register the methods without this being done first.

```
ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(IExtensionCertificateCollection), true).AddSubType(1, typeof(ExtensionCertificateCollection)); 
ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(IExtensionCertificateCollection), true).AddSubType(1, typeof(NewCollectionCerts));
server.Services.AddCodeFirst(new FakeRTC(), log: writelogs);
```